# How to remove block from left sidebar

Tags: rwd-theme

I'm using rwd package, Magento 1.8. I'm getting two blocks on left sidebar, Popular Tags and COMPANY block containing About Us, Contact us, Customer Service,
Privacy Policy. I can remove Popuar Tags using `<remove name="tags_popular"/>` in local.xml but can't get rid of COMPANY block. Any suggestions how this can be done from local.xml?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What do you mean by Company block? Can you add screenshot please?

Comment: Please see screenshot, I want to remove first purple block with heading "COMPANY"

Comment: Did you get solution? I have added answer. Check it and let me know

Answer (score 1):

You can do one of following to remove `company` block

> Choice 1 : From admin

Login to admin panel and navigate to : **`Admin > CMS > Static Blocks`**

Find **`cms_menu`** in `Identifier` column.
Open **`cms_menu`** block.

Set block status to `Disabled`.  Save CMS block.

> Choice:2 : using local.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="left">
            <remove name="cms_menu"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

**Note:** Don't forget to clear cache.

Hope this make sence to you

Comment: @raydona You can accept answer. It will help other users.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your `theme->page.xml` default block:

```
<remove name="tags_popular"/>
```

**Or**

Have a look into tag.xml where you will find this code, which you have to comment out:

```
<default>
    <!-- Mage_Tag -->
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="tag/popular" name="tags_popular" template="tag/popular.phtm">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>tag/popular.phtml</template></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I originally posted question I forgot to put <remove name="tags_popular"/> in quotes, for that reason it did not appear in question. It's the first purple block I want to remove

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been using RWD much but looking at your screenshot. I would suggest you to enable block/template hint and check which template is called in that case.

You can enable hint `template/block from System -> Configuration -> Developer -> Debug`. More reading: http://alanstorm.com/find_magento_block_name

Make sure you also select Website name as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273443/in-magento-1-9-0-0-how-can-i-enable-template-path-hint

After you find template/block name, then go to your `layout/catalog.xml` and then search for that template and find the `name` field for that template.

Then you can add below code to your local.xml

```
<remove name="your_name"/>
```

**Please replace `your_name` with the exact name you found in catalog.xml.**

Hope this makes sense to you.